# NSButton with image does not show up when disabled

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I have created an NSButton that uses an image only and no text. I create the button using the following code. The code is called from the containing window's `awakeFromNib`.

```
[[self contentView] addSubview:closeButton];
[[closeButton cell] setImageDimsWhenDisabled:YES];
[closeButton setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
[closeButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
[closeButton setBordered:NO];
[closeButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"title-close"]];
[closeButton setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"title-close-alt"]];
[closeButton setTitle:@""];
[closeButton setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
[closeButton setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
[closeButton setTarget:self];
[closeButton setAction:@selector(performClose:)];
[closeButton setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin];
if(!_hasCloseWindowButton)
[closeButton setEnabled:NO];
```

If I don't make the call to `[closeButton setEnabled:NO]` the button is drawn and works perfectly.
[image: Button Enabled]

If `[closeButton setEnabled:NO]` is called, the button is either hidden or not being drawn. 
[image: Button Disabled]

Is there some way to specify an image for the disabled state that I am somehow missing in the docs ?

Does anyone have a clue what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: So what does your disabled image look like?  You can specify something like 4 different images for a button.

Comment: (OK, for NSButton only two images -- normal and alternate.)

Comment: I'd subclass `NSButton` to add the behavior. do you really want another image tho? from the look of your sample you really want an effect, not another image.

Comment: There is the normal image which you see above and an alternate image which is just a lighter version on the normal image. I was hoping the call to setImageDimsWhenDisabled: on the button cell would get me a darker version of my normal image.